Base offence element intimate image abuse
Being as revenge porn has been introduced into the SOA 2003 and there is now in existence a summary offence of sharing an intimate image without consent does that mean that theoretically the average person could be charged with said offence for sharing via WhatsApp etc some pictures of celebrities that may have been leaked images of the kind frequently in the news, or would it basically fail the public interest test?

You're asking whether, when intimate images of B have been previously shared, whether a new sharer (A) commits the offence of sharing an intimate image when they share the image further.
The fact that intimate images of B had previously been shared is only an exception when B had, or A reasonably believes that B had, consented to the previous sharing of those images. See s. 66C(3).
Of course, whether any offence is actually charged depends on the discretion of the Crown prosecutor, including consideration of whether the prosecution would be in the public interest. This involves consideration of all the circumstances and we cannot predict how this discretion will be exercised.

My question is not whether the offence is made out. My question is hypothetically would in our case in England the CPS consider it not in the public interest to pursue a charge when the image is of the type where it may be a leaked photo of a celebrity.

@Cardgame482 If it was originally leaked to a site with relatively few users, and someone releaks it to a very popular site, the releak is more damaging to the victim. So it might be in the public interest to charge the releaker.

@barmar my point of question was a hypothetical. A celebrity leaked photo or what appears to be one is widely available online. Two people send and receive to each other said image on WhatsApp or similar. Technically the offence would be made out but in a hypothetical reality where police came upon said sharing would said offence be realistically worthwhile for the cps to consider.

I thought the question was about making the photos public, not private messages on WhatsApp.

@barman no sir my question was regarding pictures already publically available of celebrities which may have been leaked and whether it would be feasible for the cps to find it worthwhile charging members of the public who may be sharing said images privately between themselves. As by the wording of the legislation an offence could be considered to have taken place.  So scenario: celebrity questionable consent image is on website. A saves image and sends it to B on WhatsApp. The offence has theoretically been committed but would the police and cps actually pursue it?

As was explained, it depends on the circumstances. If the image was on a website with 100 viewers, and you copy it and post it on a website with 10 million viewers, changes for prosecution are high. The other way round, chances are low. Unless you post it on a site aimed at children, then prosecution would again be more likely. It depends on the circumstances.

@gnasher729 I suppose my issue with this is that the wording effectively makes privately sharing images that are widely in circulation of a famous person which 'may' have been leaked criminalised. Of course the police I imagine are unlikely should they come across such an instance of visiting Drake to get a statement. But nobody seems clear about the police/ cps not pursuing it either. Hence I asked about the public interest element.
